# Derivative of Fourier Transform to phase for Gradient descent

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, gradient-descent

My Problem is the following:
I have the complex signal over time $$f(t) = r(t)\cdot exp(i\phi(t)) \in \mathbb{C}$$ with the corresponding discrete Fourier Transform in frequency space $$s(\omega) = DFT(f(t)), \omega = [\omega_0, \omega_N]$$. 
My goal is now to change the phase $\phi(t)$ to maximize the signal $s(\omega)$ in a certain region $[\omega_a, \omega_b]$. 
The idea is to use gradient descent technique for that.
I thought about a cost-function like:
$$c(\omega) = abs \left( \frac{\sum_{i=a}^bs(\omega_i)}{\sum_{i=0}^a s(\omega_i)+\sum_{i=b}^Ns( \omega_i)}\right)$$ that is supposed to calc the ratio of the region that I want to maximize and the sourrounding.
Therefore, I need to calculate the derivate $dc(\omega)/d\phi$, but i fail to do so. Can anyone help me?

[figure showing the real part of the signal f(t) before and after changing the phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Ngs.png)

[figure showing the magnitude of the spectrum before and after changing the phase of the signal f(t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpHm.png)

Comment: What do you want to maximalize?

Comment: I would like to maximize the spectrum $s(\omega)$ in the region $\omega_a$ to $\omega_b$ by changing the phase $\phi(t)$ of my original signal $f(t)$

Comment: I saw that, but what does it mean to maximalize a function over an intervall? Do you want to maximalize $\int_{\omega_1}^{\omega_2} s$?

Comment: Yes, but since my signal is discrete, it's $\sum_{i=a}^b s(\omega_i)$. Sorry, I just realized that it was very unclear how I described my problem, is it clearer now?

Comment: I don't quite get the problem. So you have a function $f$, and you have it's fourier transform $s(\omega)=\int \mathrm{d}t e^{- i \omega t} f(t)$, which is discrete?

Comment: Maybe now it's clearer with the added images, my goal is to maximize the peak in the region from $\omega = 20$ to $\omega = 80$

Comment: So your initial function is discrete as well, right? How do you define the ft of it?

Comment: Yes, both my signal and the corresponding spectrum are discrete, the DFT is defined as follows: $ s(\omega) =\sum^N_{t=1} f(t) exp(-2\pi I /N \omega t) $